# Как вывести количество цифр после запятой?

Tags: c++

Решаю следующее задание: вводится вещественное число, необходимо вывести количество цифр после запятой (точки).

Пример:вводится 1.1221, ответ: 4 символа. Далее, 1.1, ответ: 1 символ.

Я захотел решить следующим образом: умножать число на 10, пока оно не станет целочисленным. Вопрос, как мне выйти из моего цикла? То есть, как мне задать условие, что моё вещественное число стало целочисленным?

Код прикрепляю:

```html
int second(float number_lazorin) {
  using namespace std;
  int counter_lazorin = 0;
  for(int i = 0; (int) number_lazorin == number_lazorin;i++){
    number_lazorin *= 10;
    counter_lazorin++;
  }
  cout << "\nОтлично! Ваш ответ: " << counter_lazorin << "\n\n";
}
```

Я попробовал такой способ, однако это мне не помогло. Если что, то в функцию поступает вещественное число! Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Ну попробуйте убедиться, что число равно его целой части, что-то типа `x == floor(x)`. Но, думаю, результат вас удивит малость...

Comment: Это у Вас ошибка цикла, цикл должен начинаться как: `while((int)number_lazorin != number_lazorin){ ...`.

Comment: @Harry, это ж, да, над формализацией алгоритма придётся немного поработать. Пока же: `0.9100001` -> `ответ: 2`, `0.910009` -> `ответ: 6` или `0.910001` -> `ответ: 7`